# "Unable to find installation candidates" in poetry trying to install `genicam` - how to debug?

Tags: python, python-poetry, genicam

I have just installed poetry on a windows 10 machine using the new `install-poetry.py` script. I have just converted my python application dependency management to `pyproject.toml` with `poetry`. It works for most of my dependencies, but fails for the [genicam](https://pypi.org/project/genicam/) package, with the above `Unable to find installation candidates` error message. Installing that package with `pip` does work. How do I debug such issues? I tried running `poetry install -vvv`, but all I get is the same stack-trace of poetry's internals in verbose form, nothing useful added to the output of the short-form (in particular no indexes or urls it tried and failed):

```
Package operations: 1 install, 0 updates, 0 removals

  • Installing genicam (1.1.0)

  RuntimeError

  Unable to find installation candidates for genicam (1.1.0)

  at ~\AppData\Roaming\pypoetry\venv\lib\site-packages\poetry\installation\chooser.py:72 in choose_for
       68│
       69│             links.append(link)
       70│
       71│         if not links:
    →  72│             raise RuntimeError(
       73│                 "Unable to find installation candidates for {}".format(package)
       74│             )
       75│
       76│         # Get the best link
```

I'm using poetry version 1.1.13 on python 3.8.10 on windows 10 (python 3.8 is the latest supported by `genicam` - it's a closed source package managed by the GenICam consortium, and they have a ridiculous release process; somehow they need a committee voting before they can release a new package - end rant).

Comment: Try cleaning the cache by `poetry cache clear --all pypi` and run `poetry install` again.

Comment: `poetry cache clear`didn't help. My problem was in fact that I my `pyproject.toml` specified `python = "^3.8"` which was resolved by poetry to select python 3.9; the only one it found. Fixing did lead to an issue where poetry [doesn't use pyenv python even when it was activated](https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/issues/651), when poetry is installed using the new `install-poetry.py`. The original question still stands though: How would I debug the issue (i.e. if poetry had told me it uses python 3.9, I would have been much quicker here).

Comment: `poetry env info` should show which Python is used for the virtual environment.

Comment: try `poetry cache clear --all pypi` and also `poetry config installer.max-workers 1`

Answer (score 12):

Had a dependency to a repository using an authentication token which were expired. Updating auth credentials fixed this.

Answer (score 2):

Similar to Jakob Kristensen's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74808456/1966465) (thanks for the pointer), in my case the **access tokens had expired**. Here's a longer winded answer on how I solved it.

---

The Access Tokens to the desired repositories had expired:

- You can create new Personal Access Tokens in your [GitLab](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/profile/personal_access_tokens.html#create-a-personal-access-token)/[GitHub](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/managing-your-personal-access-tokens#creating-a-fine-grained-personal-access-token)/[Bitbucket](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucketserver076/personal-access-tokens-1026534797.html) account.
- If the access to the repository is tied to another project, look into [Project Access Tokens](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/user/project/settings/project_access_tokens.html) (analog for GitHub/BitBucket).

Poetry saves the authentication method in the `poetry.toml` file:

- Update the access tokens with the `poetry config http-basic.$SOURCENAME $USERNAME $PASSWORD` command.

  - Note: here $SOURCENAME refers to how the source was named in the `pyproject.toml` file and **not** to the name of the repository!
- See the poetry documentation
  on [Configuring Credentials](https://python-poetry.org/docs/repositories/#configuring-credentials) for more information.

If the issue is occurring in Gitlab-CI, you may use `poetry config http-basic.$SOURCENAME gitlab-ci-token "${CI_JOB_TOKEN}"`.