# Poetry unable to find candidates for aiohttp

Tags: python, aiohttp, python-poetry

Couldn't find the answer on internet, so I want you to ask some questions. Currently, I have a problem installing aiohttp with python 3.11 using poetry. The question is, why poetry makes such a problem? I'm getting common error:

```
poetry add aiohttp       
Using version ^3.9.1 for aiohttp

Updating dependencies
Resolving dependencies... (4.6s)

Package operations: 62 installs, 1 update, 0 removals

  • Updating charset-normalizer (2.1.1 -> 3.3.2)
  • Installing pywin32 (227): Failed

  RuntimeError

  Unable to find installation candidates for pywin32 (227)

  at ~\.virtualenvs\flight_radar-mhtNZ9NU\Lib\site-packages\poetry\installation\chooser.py:73 in choose_for
       69│
       70│             links.append(link)
       71│
       72│         if not links:
    →  73│             raise RuntimeError(f"Unable to find installation candidates for {package}")
       74│
       75│         # Get the best link
       76│         chosen = max(links, key=lambda link: self._sort_key(package, link))
       77│

Cannot install pywin32.
```

Which means, poetry can't find a library even if aiohttp is supported on python 3.11. Is there any reasonable solution for this?

Another question is why to use poetry if it is not better than pipenv or pip? If pipenv or pip can handle installing libraries, for what for poetry is needed? I'm a little frustrated, because everyone tells that it is the best dependency management, but on my every project based on python 3.10/3.11, I'm always having a problem with it. Funny thing is that, pip or pipenv works fine. Again, what's the point of existing poetry? Should I use it, or just forget? Just asking, because it will be my 4th project based on new python, where i have to remove poetry and use a pipenv.

Comment: Does [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71802816/unable-to-find-installation-candidates-in-poetry-trying-to-install-genicam) help? In general, poetry is going to do a good job of 1.) ensuring that your dependencies are mutually compatible, 2.) building and publishing your project in a single command (`poetry build`/`poetry publish`).

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't help at all. I see your point of view, but still, it's more problematic than for example pipenv. On my EVERY project, I have a problem with poetry, which I don't have with pipenv. I don't understand the magic of poetry. Every time I start work with it, and it's already cool, at the end I find that I have to switch to pipenv because poetry can't handle some library. And its always the same error with pywin32.

Comment: Okay, well, this isn’t the place to discuss the general merits and demerits of one v the other. I would suggest that you sharpen up your question with more details about your environment and how the linked question differs from your question.